# Simulation nodes softbody

Tags: soft-body, simulation-nodes

I’m trying to do a softbody simulation in gemoetry nodes. Basically what I’m doing is calculating a “relative position” for each vertex by subtracting position from edge position (position evaluated on edge domain). I then store that as a an “init_pos” named attribute, and in the simulation zone I calculate the same thing and subtract it from the init_position. I use the resultant vector as the velocity, which I scale by a “tension” factor before adding it to the previous frame’s velocity. I cap this velocity at 0.8 m/s to prevent the vertices from flying off, and finally I use a set position node to offset the vertices by a fraction of the velocity (a “time step” factor). My full node tree is below:

[image]

Now the best balance I’ve been able to get is a “tension” factor of 7 and a “time step” of 0.2, but it seems to run in slow motion (see image).

[image]

When I try to increase either the tension or time step any further, however, instead of simulating faster I get this weird jittery vertex effect (see image). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT: When I turn off the velocity capping, the jitter keeps increasing in amplitude till the vertices fly off the screen.

Here is the [blend file](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/sFQJ31PgBRcRJOdjeeKKsNhINTB.blend) if it helps.